# Call chainlink from other smart contract?

Tags: ethereum, solidity

I need to get a value from an array which I read through a chainlink oracle. So far so good, but I need that value in another contract to make use of it, how could I make this happen?

Also, how can I make a combined payment, when someone buys one Service, the money would also be used to pay the gas for the Chainlink fee?

thanks!

Comment: Hi, Stackoverflow works best when you try stuff, it doesn't work, you share the code, and *then* we comment on it.

Answer (score 0):

To read a value from a Chainlink data feed, you need to pass a feed's address to the `AggregatorV3Interface.sol` interface.

```
AggregatorV3Interface dataFeed = AggregatorV3Interface(0x9326....);
```

You then can call the interface's `latestRoundData()` function, which returns a tuple of values that contain the information you requested. For an example price feed:

```
(
  uint80 roundID, 
  int price,
  uint startedAt,
  uint timeStamp,
  uint80 answeredInRound
) = priceFeed.latestRoundData();
```

See https://docs.chain.link/docs/get-the-latest-price/ for more details.

When you say combined payment, what do you mean? If the Chainlink data feed call (as above) is called during a transaction, that transaction's gas will be used to pay for the computation. So if a user buys a service and sends gas with that call, and then in that call the data feed is called, the original sender's gas will be used to call the data feed method.

Comment: Well I need to read a value from a JSON file so a normal oracle with a get module works, I actually figured it out but now the problem is, that when multiple users would use it to get the information different specific items from that JSON Array, only the last one gets called and the others are ignored